# How to overwrite duplicates, append new rows based on a specific cell value using Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

[Draft Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHYpj.png)

[Finalized Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqG1Y.png)

Hi all, in need of help here.

Right now, I have two tabs: Finalized & Draft. Draft contains the new, updated employee information for the company whereas Finalized contains the old information.

Basically, I want to compare the differences between both tabs based on the name column. New records in the Draft Tab Eg. Charlie and Zach would be added the finalized tab, whereas existing records such as Amy and Ben would be overwritten so that I capture changes in other columns ie. Marital Status of Amy.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having with getting this done?  Do you have some code to share?

Comment: Hey Tim, I am quite new to VBA, so I am not really quite sure on how to start.